# How to expand a tree view as maximum of content in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How could we can expand a Treeview width as maximum of its node content width ?
I have attached a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYzQC.png) of the current view. I a have not given any size or changed any property value.

I just want to get the width after expanded and need to give that as SplitContainer SplitterDistance to keep the panel width as treeview width.

Comment: Make the width of the control (treeview) the width of the form (minus some border).  treeview1.Width = this.Width - 20.

Comment: You'll have to use the TreeNode.Bounds property.  But this changes as the user expands the nodes so that's fairly unpractical.  The point of using a SplitContainer is to let the user adjust this to his liking so helping doesn't make much sense anyway.  Just dock the TreeView into the splitter's panel and set the Panel1MinSize property to a reasonable value.